# Getting empty string instead of undefined from unset attributes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes

The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) states that

> As of jQuery 1.6, the `.attr()` method returns `undefined` for attributes that have not been set.

However, I have a case where I'd like a method to return `undefined` if I go looking for an attribute that is not *defined*, but an empty string for attributes that have been set to have no value.

Given the following markup:

```
<p data-withvalue="hello there!" data-novalue="">
```

I'd like javascript that works like this:

```
$('p').attr('data-withvalue') => "hello there!"
$('p').attr('data-novalue') => ""
$('p').attr('data-notthere') => undefined
```

Downgrading jQuery is not an option. Is this possible?

(Note: looking at "inspect element" in the Chrome developer tools, I note that `data-novalue=""` has been changed to `data-novalue`. I don't know if all browsers interpret it like that, but I need this to be cross-browser compatible...)

Comment: added as my fav question and +1 looking forward to its answer..nice question!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, that's exactly how it's working with jQuery 1.6.2

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xJfpX/

Output:

```
hello there!

undefined
```

Comment: Yup - turn's out I'm a clutz. I was, without realizing it, looking for `data-data-novalue`, which of course returned `undefined`. Thanks!